# Unable to execute an Amazon CLI command in ruby script

Tags: json, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am able to run certain CLI commands but however, I getting an error when the CLI command `aws iam create-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::899163431116:policy/cloudhealth-access-policy --policy-document file://\Users\kougav01\Desktop\GitCH\v2.json --set-as-default --profile jo`

executes in my script,however, it executes perfectly on command prompt.

THE ERROR MESSAGE: `Error parsing parameter '--policy-document': Unable to load paramfile file://Userskougav01DesktopGitCH♂2.json: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: u'Userskougav01DesktopGitCH\x0b2.json'`

MY CODE LOOKS LIKE:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'

#current CloudHealth API restricts
 j = RestClient.get 'https://chapi.cloudhealthtech.com/v1/aws_accounts?api_key=#####&page=1&per_page=100'
 j2 = RestClient.get 'https://chapi.cloudhealthtech.com/v1/aws_accounts?api_key=######&page=2&per_page=100'
 my_hash = JSON.parse(j)
 my_hash2 = JSON.parse(j2)
 accnt_size = my_hash["aws_accounts"].size
 intaccntsize = accnt_size.to_i
 account_number_array = Array.new
 my_hash["aws_accounts"].each do |account|
  if account["status"]["level"] == "yellow"
    account_number_array << account["owner_id"]
  end
end
my_hash2["aws_accounts"].each do |account|
  if account["status"]["level"] == "yellow"
    account_number_array << account["owner_id"]
  end
end
puts "Here are the accounts that have an warning(status = yellow)"
puts
puts account_number_array.inspect
puts "1.) Making the changes so the policy will have the addittion of elasticfilesystem:Describe*, es:Describe* and es:ListTags"


accnt = [899163431116, 2382308203823, 8989089089080]

`aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::#{accnt[0]}:policy/cloudhealth-access-policy --version-id v2 --profile jo`

    account_number_array.each do |awsid|
    `aws iam create-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::#{awsid}:policy/cloudhealth-access-policy --policy-document file://\Users\kougav01\Desktop\GitCH\v2.json --set-as-default --profile jo`
    end
```

Essentially, I have an bunch of account numbers from an API call that need to have an updated policy, I am updating the policy using an CLI command and uploading a .json file for a new version(v2.json).

Comment: Try file:///Users/kougav01/Desktop/GitCH/v2.json.

Comment: thanks that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the file `file://Userskougav01DesktopGitCH♂2.json` is invalid -- it's missing the directory slashes `/`.

Comment: why does it work if I run it on the command prompt and not in the ruby script. ??

Comment: Ah, you need to escape the backslashes. Just use ruby's `File.join()` to join the different parts of your path. So for the relevant part of that line: `--policy-document file://#{File.join('/Users', 'kougav1', 'Desktop', 'GitCH', 'v2.json')}`